# Как передвинуть итератор сразу на несколько позиций?

Tags: stl, c++

Для разъяснения читаем исходник:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    list<int> l;

    l.push_back(10);
    l.push_back(20);
    l.push_back(30);
    l.push_back(40);
    l.push_back(50);

    list<int>::iterator it = l.begin();
    it++; // как не прибегая к такому способу сдвинуть итератор сразу на 3 позиции?

    l.insert(it, 22);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть хороший метод [advance](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/?kw=advance). Он умеет сдвигать итератор на нужное число в нужную сторону.

Comment: Спасибо, @KoVadim, вы, как всегда, на высоте.

Comment: Добавлю, что для итераторов произвольного доступа можно пользоваться просто оператором `+`: http://ideone.com/AqbAvS

Comment: @VladD для типа list это работать не будет.

Comment: У list итератора произвольного доступа как раз и нет.